# Migrating ActiveModel::Serializer down from v0.9.2 to 0.8, has_many not being serialised

Tags: ruby-on-rails, active-model-serializers

I have the following `ActiveModel::Serializer` class

```
class MyThingySerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  root false

  attributes :id, :name, :description

  has_many :whatsits, embed_namespace: :_embedded

  delegate :whatsits, to: :object

end
```

It was working fine under AMS 0.9.2 but, in order to add an optional attribute using the `include_attributename?` mechanism I was told to roll-back to AMS 0.8

Now my `whatsits` don't appear in my serialised output under the `_embedded` attribute.

Is there something special I need to do to get my embedded `whatsits` back?

**Update**

I've tried adding the following method to my Serializer:

```
def whatsits
  associated = self.class._associations[:whatsits]
  associated.options[:root] = associated.options[:embed_namespace]
  associated.options[:embed] = :objects
  associated.options[:include] = true
  object.whatsits
end
```

Hoping that would get the Serializer to emit the `whatsits` list under the `_embedded` key, but alas that didn't work..

Comment: The api for 0.8 is here https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/tree/8d31f7ee8c0ea3ed83ab871765f1444291278b41#embedding-associations there is no `embed_namespace`. Possibly `has_many :whatsits, root: :_embedded`

Comment: Alas no changing `embed_namespace` to `root` doesn't help.  I'll just have to do it manually I think. Roll on AMS v0.10

Answer (score 0):

This works.

```
class MyThingySerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  root false

  attributes :id, :name, :description, :_embedded

  # force the whatsits list to sit under '_embedded'.
  def _embedded
    {
      whatsits: object. whatsits.map {|whatsit| WhatsitSerializer.new(whatsit) } || []
    }
  end
end
```